# Prove that $\sigma = \tau =e $

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\sigma , \tau $ are two permuations that disturb no common element and $\sigma  \tau = e$ , prove that $\sigma = \tau =e $

Comment: I understand that they commute since they are disjoint, and I understand it with an example, but I just don't know how to generally prove it.

Comment: Suppose they are not $e$. What happens if $\tau$ moves some element? Can $\sigma$ move it back?

Comment: Try proving the converse statement: If $\sigma\tau=e$ and $\sigma\neq e$, then there is some element that both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ disturb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sigma(k)\ne k$. By hypothesis $\tau(k)=k$, so $(\sigma\tau)(k)=\sigma\big(\tau(k)\big)=\sigma(k)\ne k$, and $\sigma\tau\ne e$.

**Added:** You can even get $\tau=e$ without knowing that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ commute. Suppose that $\tau(k)\ne k$; say $\tau(k)=\ell$. Then clearly $\tau(\ell)\ne\ell$, so $\sigma(\ell)=\ell$. Thus, $(\sigma\tau)(k)=\sigma\big(\tau(k)\big)=\sigma(\ell)=\ell\ne k$, and again $\sigma\tau\ne e$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\sigma \neq e$ then $\sigma$ disturbs some element $a$ sending it to $b$ and $\tau$ sends $b$ to $a$, which it cannot do without moving $a$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x$, assume for the sake of contradiction that $\tau x \ne x$.  Since $\tau$ disturbs $x$, $\sigma$ does not, so $\sigma \tau x \ne x$.  This contradicts the claim that $\sigma \tau = e$.  So $\tau = e$, and $\sigma \tau = e$ so $\sigma = e$.